# Does Python have a module to convert CSS styles to inline styles for emails?

Tags: python, css

I know this exists in other languages, but I want it for Python to I can send emails that'll show up in GMail, etc.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#id3

Comment: I don't know of any such module. I think it requires some programming effort. CSS matching problems that come to mind are: (1) class="class1 class2" (2) multiple qualifiers (like div.class, id.class, class.class, etc.). If your CSS has only one-segment matching rules, your translation will be much easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had to do the same thing a while back and put the module I made for it up on GitHub https://github.com/rennat/pynliner

Answer (score 14):

There are now many choices for this. Here are two more in what seems to be decreasing order of activity:

- [Premailer](https://github.com/peterbe/premailer)
- [Inline Styler](https://github.com/davecranwell/inline-styler)

Comment: Great research!  now i have options!

Comment: Premailer looks like the most up to date, as of this date.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone visiting this in 2022 then the other option would be : https://pypi.org/project/css-inline/

As per the site response time is below:

```
css_inline 0.8.2 - 22.42 us
premailer 3.10.0 - 332.02 us (x14.81)
toronado 0.1.0 - 1.59 ms (x71.17)
inlinestyler 0.2.5 - 2.35 ms (x105.07)
pynliner 0.8.0 - 2.79 ms (x124.80)
```

Answer (score 0):

[toronado](https://pypi.org/project/toronado/) is Fast lxml-based CSS stylesheet inliner.

Installation : 
pip install toronado

Example :

```
import toronado
document = """<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      h1 { color: red; }
   </style>
</head>
<body><h1>Hello, world.</h1></body>
</html>"""
print(toronado.from_string(document))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and if you just need a one-off conversion, you can use this website https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

I just needed to convert my template one time and this worked for me

Answer (score -3):

http://blog.doughellmann.com/2008/10/pymotw-smtplib.html great example from doug

Comment: From a quick glance I don't see any relevance. Am I missing something?

Comment: OP wants a lib that can covert all css to inline so it can be used for email templates.