# How to set default styles for Markdown in email

Tags: python, django, templates, markdown

I am using [Django-Markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux) to render HTML for an email template.

Consider the following input:

```
# Heading 1
Text goes here
```

This would render as:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Text goes here</p>
```

Is there a way to add default styles for each element? Note *styles* need to be inline as this is email. E.g:

```
<h1 style="color:#eee;font-family:'Helvetica Neue'">Heading 1</h1>
```

Comment: Is the Markdown being rendered by the email client or by another tool before being copied to the email client? In either case, it might help to know which tool you are using to render the Markdown to HTML.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged "django"? I don't see the connection.

Comment: If the "django" tag means that you are looking for a solution to use from within Django, then perhaps you wanted to tag it "Python". If so, then this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960721/866026), which points to a few different Python libraries that may address the problem.

Comment: @Waylan thanks, I am using Django-Markdown-Deux as the filter, hence the Django tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that can be done by Markdown itself. However, there are some Python libraries which will take HTML input (and some CSS) and output reformatted HTML with inline styles (as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5173388/866026) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990942/866026) point out). Therefore you would need to take the output of Markdown and pass it into one of those libraries.

As you are using a Django template filter (I'm assuming  the filter rather than the Tag provided by Deux) to render the Markdown to HTML, you will need to create a second filter which wraps one of the CSS inliner libraries and pass the output of the Markdown filter to your custom filter. Your custom filter might look something like this (untested):

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from pynliner import Pynliner

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="html2email")
def pynliner_filter(value):
    css = "h1 {color:#eee; font-family:'Helvetica Neue'}"
    p = Pynliner()
    return mark_safe(p.from_string(value).with_cssString(css).run())
```

Then, in your template, you would do:

```
{{ myvar|markdown|html2email }}
```

It may be interesting to note that I hardcoded the CSS right in the filter. Expanding this to be customizable is left as an exercise for the reader. Fore more specific information on creating and loading custom template filters, see [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/).

---

If you have styles defined in the template (in `<style>` tags), then those styles would presumably need to apply to the entire document (not just the part generated by Markdown).  Note that the inliner tools will accept a complete HTML file (with CSS defined within it) and output a file which has those styles inlined. If that is your situation, then you will not need to use the custom template filter.  Instead, after rendering the template, you will need to pass the HTML document through an inliner tool within your Django view. Perhaps something like this:

```
def someview(...)
    # Do your pre-template stuff here ...
    html = template.render()
    p = Pyliner()
    email_body = p.from_string(html).run()
    # Send your email here (or whatever you are doing) ...
```

Without more info about your specific situation, the above code leaves a lot out. Only the relevant bits to this specific issue are addressed. There is a lot more to have a working view. Although, if you already have a working view, then presumably you would only need to replace the line which renders the template with the few lines shown above.

Comment: Thanks, good solution. If I wanted to apply `<style>` within the template to the filter instead of hardcoded CSS, where would I start?

Comment: @alias51 I added to my answer a section about how to  apply styles defined within `<style>` tags within the template.